# How to pass on multiple intents output to one single intent to execute

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

Consider I want to build a system which plays audio and video

Intents I will have are

1. Ask user what he/she wants (Audio or video)
2. Play audio or video depending on previous intent.

I want to reuse the intent 2 (player for audio or video) without having two intents one for each audio and video.

I'm planning my intents and contexts like below

```
Bot: What you want to play
User: Play me audio
Bot: plays audio (using same player intent)
User: Play me video
Bot: plays video (using same player intent)
```

Is it possible? if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this isn't through a different Intent - but rather through Fulfillment.

Intents are for handling *what the user says*, and not how to respond to what they say. Fulfillment lets you look at parameters that have been set and send an appropriate response.